# Access / identify Role GroupMembers in Apex

Tags: soql, roles, public-group

If I know the Role Id of the logged in the User. Can I determine which Groups the Role Id is associated with?

When I query the GroupMember object - using something like this

```
SELECT Id, Group.Type, GroupId, UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember where GroupId = '00G8E000000mgQ2'
```

I can see the correct total of records - but not sure how to query based on the Role Id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query [Group Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_group.htm) directly for that

```
[Select Id,Name from Group where RelatedId =:roleID]
```

Comment: :) .Glad it helped :)